# Semiring of event sequences is compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a finite set and let $\Omega=E^\mathbb{N}$ be the space of $E$-valued sequences. We define the set of all sequences whose first $n$ values are $\omega_1,\cdots\omega_n$:
\begin{equation}
[\omega_1,\cdots\omega_n] := \{\omega'\in\Omega:\omega'_i=\omega_i\;\mathrm{for\;any\;}i=1,\cdots,n\}.
\end{equation}

Define $\mathcal{A}=\{[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n]:\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n\in E,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Let $A,A_1,A_2,\ldots\in\mathcal{A}$ and $A\subset\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}A_n$. Show that there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $A\subset\bigcup^N_{n=1}A_n$.

*Proof* Let $B_n:=A\setminus\bigcup^n_{i=1}A_i$. We assume $B_n\neq\emptyset$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ in order to get a contradiction. By Dirichlet's pigeonhole principle (recall that $E$ is finite), we can choose $B_1\supset B_2\supset\ldots$ , we obtain $[\omega_1]\cap B_n\neq\emptyset$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Successively choose $\omega_2,\omega_3\ldots\in E$ in such a way that $[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_k]\cap B_n\neq\emptyset$ for all $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$. $B_n$ is a disjoint union of certain sets $C_{n,1},\ldots,C_{n,m_n}\in\mathcal{A}$. Hence, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is an $i_n\in\{1,\ldots,m_n\}$ such that $[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_k]\cap C_{n,i_n}\neq\emptyset$ for infinitely many $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $[\omega_1]\supset[\omega_1,\omega_2]\supset\ldots$, we obtain $[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_k]\cap C_{n,i_n}\neq\emptyset$ for all $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$.  For fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and large k, we have $[\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_k]\subset C_{n,i_n}$. Hence $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots)\in C_{n,i_n}\subset B_n$. This implies $\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}B_n\neq\emptyset$, contradicting the assumption.

My question:

Why the final conclusion is contradicting the assumption? It seems to me that it is the same as the assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final contradiction is $\bigcap_n B_n \neq \emptyset$, while the starting assumption $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n1}^\infty A_n$ implies that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n = \emptyset$: if $x \notin A$, then $x \notin B_n$ for any $n$ and if $x \in A$, for some $m$, $X \in A_m$ but then $x \notin B_m$ and so $x \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ too. That is what the proof means "by contradicting the assumption".

A simpler topological proof can be obtained by noting that all members of $\mathcal{A}$ are *clopen* in $E^{\Bbb N}$ (compact zero-dimensional in the product topology) and so in particular $A$ is compact and is covered by open sets $A_n, n \in \Bbb N$ and hence by finitely many.

Comment: I know this is an easier proof. But I just want to know how the posted elementary proof works.

Comment: @JunkWarrior I added that too.